# Blackberry simulator DNS error connecting to localhost

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I discovered that when am on a network and connecting to my localhost(glassfish) on port 8095(changed the port number), my simulator connects fast and easy, but without a network, it doesn's connect and popups out this "DNS error" while connecting to the same glassfish server. My MDS is up and no proxy configured. So what do you think is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 127.0.0.1? That's what 'localhost' ought to resolve to anyway.